# recorrer última dimensión de array bidimensional

Tags: php

Estoy empezando a entender arrays multidimensionales en PHP y tengo una duda.
Supongamos que tengo este array bidimensional:

```
$auto[0][0] = "fiat";
$auto[0][1] = "italia";

$auto[1][0] = "bmw";
$auto[1][1] = "alemania";

$auto[2][0] = "toyota";
$auto[2][1] = "japón";
```

Es posible recorrer solo la última dimensión, obteniendo: "Italia", "Alemania", "Japón"

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un bucle [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php). De esta manera, `$a` representará cada una de las filas del array (tomando el array multidimensional como filas y columnas) y como tus países siempre están en la posición 1 (columna 1 de cada fila), podrás acceder a la posición 1 de la fila `$a`.

Su utilización sería:

```
foreach($auto as $a){
    echo $a[1] . " ";
}
```

Lo que te dará la siguiente salida:

```
italia alemania japón
```

Answer (score 1):

**No, no es posible recorrer solo la última dimensión**. Deberás recorrer las dimensiones anteriores primero para poder obtener algún valor en la ultima dimensión.

Para ello yo consider que deberias usar alguna de las siguientes estructuras de control (existen otras mas):

- [foreach](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

  ```
  $countries = array();
  foreach ($auto as $info) {
    $countries[] = $info[1];
  }
  echo implode($countries, ',');
  ```
- [for](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php)

  ```
  $countries = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($auto); $i++) {
    $countries[] = $auto[$i][1];
  }
  echo implode($countries, ',');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Sí puedes** recorrer la última dimensión:

```
// Recorres las filas
for($i = 0; $i < count($auto); $i++)
{
  $ultimo_elemento = count( $auto[$i]);

  echo $auto[$i][$ultimo_elemento - 1];
}
```

Iteras fila por fila tantas como tenga la matriz. Luego obtienes la cantidad de elementos por cada fila, eso -1 = último elemento ya que los array se enumeran a partir del 0.